# Spotlight search doesn't work when app not running

Tags: ios, swift2, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotification

I want to tell first `UIViewController` that Spotlight opened it. I try to make it by `NSNotificationCenter`. But I tried several methods and they don't it when I make my key like "spotlightOpen". When I use standard name like `UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification` it works for me. Below I wrote several methods which I tried

In

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
       NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("selectSong", object: nil)

        return true
}
```

In First controller

```
  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName("selectSong", object: nil, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (NSNotification) -> Void in
        print("Song table is loaded")
    }
```

Still I made it in the first controller. But it too didn't work for me.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "selectedSong", name: "selectSong", object: nil)

 func application(application: UIApplication, continueUserActivity userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: ([AnyObject]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    print("continueUserActivity")
    userDefault.setBool(true, forKey: "applicationDelegateOpen")
    if userActivity.activityType == CSSearchableItemActionType {
        print("CSSearchableItemActionType")
        if let identifier = userActivity.userInfo?[CSSearchableItemActivityIdentifier] {
            userDefault.setValue(identifier, forKey: "spotlightIdentifier")
            userDefault.setBool(true, forKey: "spotlightBool")
            print(identifier)
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it. It works for me

```
 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
            super.viewDidAppear(animated)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.tabBarController!.tabBar.hidden = false
            fetchFilesFromFolder()
            //
            checkSpotlightResult()
        }     
       func checkSpotlightResult() {
                print("checkSpotlightResult")
        //        print(arrayForCheckSpot)
        //        userDefault.setValue(identifier, forKey: "spotlightIdentifier")
        //        userDefault.setBool(true, forKey: "spotlightBool")
        //        var boolCheckSpot: Bool!
        //        var identifierCheckSpot: String!
                boolCheckSpot = userDefault.boolForKey("spotlightBool")
                if boolCheckSpot != nil {
                    if boolCheckSpot == true {
                    identifierCheckSpot = userDefault.valueForKey("spotlightIdentifier") as! String
                    if arrayForCheckSpot.contains(identifierCheckSpot) {
        //                print("Array title contains \(identifierCheckSpot)")
                        let index = arrayForCheckSpot.indexOf(identifierCheckSpot)!
                        let myIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 0)
                        print(myIndexPath)
                        self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(myIndexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .None)
                        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("listenMusic", sender: self)
                        userDefault.setBool(false, forKey: "spotlightBool")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that on a cold launch that your view controller hasn't been initialized yet. You need to temporarily save that notification data until something like `loadView` or `viewDidLoad` is called.

Comment: I still tried when first UIViewController is loaded I pass Notification to the second UIViewController but I got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

In the `continueUserActivity` callback of `UIApplicationDelegate`, you can handle the NSUserActivity of type `CSSearchableItemActionType` for spotlight actions, if you are using the `CoreSpotlight` API. If you are using `NSUserActivity` API, you can also handle those in this delegate callback.

You create a core spotlight item with your song ID:

```
let item = CSSearchableItem(uniqueIdentifier: songId, domainIdentifier: "com.mycompany.song", attributeSet: attributeSet)
// ... Save it and all that
```

You can handle the spotlight launch using:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, continueUserActivity userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: ([AnyObject]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    if userActivity.activityType == CSSearchableItemActionType {
        if let songId = userActivity.userInfo?[CSSearchableItemActivityIdentifier] as? String {
            // Do notification with songId
            // Or let view controllers know about selected songId
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did. But when app is not launch I want to open the specific songs, it doesn't work. It just opens app.

Comment: I can to open the specific file from spotlight when app is in background but when app is not launching this method just opens app.

Comment: yes, I did it. My problem that it doesn't work when not running. When app not running spotlight only opens app.

Comment: I think you have a different bug then.

Comment: No, I have only one problem. When application is not running, spotlight search opens only app, but it doesn't any function. when app is in background it very works.